# Axios override, get status code from the data response instead of status

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm calling an API that defines the statusCode from data instead of the response code:

```
{
  data: {
     statusCode: 422,
     message: "User's not found"
  }, 
 status: 200
}
```

In my axios get request it's getting the status code from the status instead in data.

```
return axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/users`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
```

I'm getting the response but it should go to catch since it's 422.

How can I refer to the statusCode of the data response so that if it's not 200 it should go to catch statement

Comment: I think the problem is from the backend side, backend should return 422 status code instead of 200

Comment: Yes I'm also thinking the backend should handle the status code properly. but is there any way I can refer from the statusCode of the data response?

Answer (score 4):

You can intercept the response, inspect the data and throw a custom error in this case:

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    if (response.data && response.data.statusCode && !(response.data.statusCode >= 200 && response.data.statusCode < 300)) throw new Error()
    return response;
}, function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

// Make a GET request
axios.get(url)
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('data', data)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log('error', e)
    })
```

This way you configure your axios instance so you dont have to repeat yourself for every single request in your app

Also, you can override the status using following code. **But since status validation has already executed, it will not throw errors on bad status codes**

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    if (response.data && response.data.statusCode) response.status = response.data.statusCode
    return response;
}, function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: Dude you're my hero of the day!! :) That's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can handle with standard `if` statement inside the `.then()`

```
return axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/users`)
      .then(response => {
        if(response.data.statusCode===442){
           ...//custom error handling goes here
        }else{
           ...//if statusCode is a success one
        }      
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `response.data.statusCode` value, if it is `442` then you should ideally throw an `Error` and let it be handled in the `.catch` callback.

```
return axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/users`)
      .then(response => {
        if(response.data.statusCode===442){
           throw new Error(response.data.message); //using throw instead of Promise.reject() to break the control flow. 
        }else{
           //return the data wrapped in promise
        }      
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message);
          return Promise.reject(err.message);
      });
```